# Select/Update column based on uid/nid (don't overwrite/ignore duplicates)

Tags: database

**Short Overview**

I'm (attempting) to build a video tracking system in drupal 7 but am having trouble with database inserts and updates.  I have my table with four fields from my .install which looks like:

```
UID   NID          stats                        progress
 1     9    ["1","2", ..."99", "100"]     0 (only 1 if stats = 100% completed)
```

On my front end, there is a script sending these three fields, excluding progress, to the back end and storing it. I then do a simple calculation based on the stats array, which determines the progress column for that nid for that uid in php.

Of course NID will change based on which node they are on, and UID changes based on each user.

**My problem is writing a query for**:

`if($nid == ...->fields('nid') && $uid == ...->fields('uid'))`

basically *if an entry already exists for this user on this node, update and append to the stats column, not overwrite it*.

and also to check something like:

```
if(empty(stats) && if($nid != ...->fields('nid') && $uid != ...->fields('uid'))
```

*if an entry for this user on this node doesn't exist, then create a new entry?*

I've looked into the schema api and am having trouble selecting a column based on these conditions.

Comment: What type is the `stats` column?

Comment: Stats is varchar

Comment: I wouldn't bother trying to do that in a single query (it's possible, but it'd be complicated and messy because of the format of the `stats` column; MySQL doesn't understand that). Much easier to select the data, if you find it, use what you've got and update, and if you don't, add a new record

Comment: Complicated and messy describes the past couple of hours for me! Hearing someone with more MySQL experience break it up into chunks helps. Thank you Clive.